# Node csv-parse halting after 16 rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I'm experiencing very weird behavior running csv-parse in the following setup:
csv - ^1.1.0
stream-transform - ^0.1.1
node - v4.6.0

And running the following code to transform CSVs into an array of objects:

```
var parse = require('csv').parse
var fs = require('fs')
var streamtransform = require('stream-transform')

function mapCsvRow(headers, record) {
  return record.reduce((p, c, i) => {
    p[headers[i]] = c //eslint-disable-line
    return p
  }, {})
}

function parseFile(path) {
  var headers
  var output = []
  var parser = parse({ delimiter: ',' })
  var input = fs.createReadStream(path)

  var transformer = streamtransform((record) => {
    if (!headers) {
      headers = record
      return record
    }

    output.push(mapCsvRow(headers, record))
    return record
  })

  // Return a new promise to wrap the parsing stream
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    input
      .pipe(parser)
      .pipe(transformer)
      .on('error', e => reject(e))
      .on('finish', () => resolve(output))
  })
}

module.exports = parseFile
```

module.exports = parseFile
What happens is that the parser halts on processing files larger than 16 records. No error, no finish, no nothing.

I have no idea how to debug this, I couldn't get any input from the parser when that happens.

Comment: Does your `.csv` file contain any additional commas in any of the rows/rowdata?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have reader stream and transformer stream, but you don't have any writer stream. Hence transformer stream gets full and pauses read stream.

Try rewrite your code to not use output array. It's pointless to use stream if you hold results in memory.